# How to get the start and end of a calendar week as LocalDateTime (java 8)

Tags: java, date, formatting, localdatetime

I want to transform the following String:

```
private String cw = "35/19"
```

into 2 dates.

The start date can be formatted with:

```
private final DateTimeFormatter startOfWeekFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
   .appendPattern("ww/YY")
   .parseDefaulting(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), 1)
   .toFormatter();
```

which when called returns: 26.08.2019

```
LocalDate.parse(cw, startOfWeekFormat).atStartOfDay();
```

But I struggle with the end of the week which is basically the start of the next week "36/19".

I tried to add plus 8 days, but that throws an exception:

```
private final DateTimeFormatter endOfWeekFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("ww/YY")
    .parseDefaulting(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), 8)
    .toFormatter();
```

Comment: Do you have to get the end of a calendar week directly? If not, you could simply add a week to the start, which can be successfully parsed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
LocalDateTime ldt=LocalDate.parse(cw, startOfWeekFormat)
                    .atStartOfDay()
                    .with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.time.temporal.WeekFields;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cw = "35/19";
        final DateTimeFormatter startOfWeekFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                            .appendPattern("ww/YY")
                                            .parseDefaulting(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), 1)
                                            .toFormatter();
        
        LocalDateTime ldt=LocalDate.parse(cw, startOfWeekFormat)
                            .atStartOfDay()
                            .with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2019-09-02T00:00
```

Comment: I'd prefer an solution where I don't need to add the additional days to the result of the parsed string. Like a solution where the "plus(8)" is already included in the formatter.

Comment: @Spektakulatius - A week has `7` days and therefore you can not add `8` as you have mentioned in your question. You need to replace `8` with `7`. Also, the equivalent result can be obtained by using `.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));` in my answer. The second thing I would like to mention is, an idiomatic way to add days to a `LocalDateTime` is by using `.plusDays(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer that adds a week, but in a different way:

I assume you always want the start date and the end date of a calendar week. You could write a method that returns a `Map.Entry<LocalDate, LocalDate>` where the key is the start date and the value is the end date.

It could look like this:

```
public static Map.Entry<LocalDate, LocalDate> getStartAndEndOfCalendarWeek(String calendarWeek) {
    DateTimeFormatter startOfWeekFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("ww/YY")
            .parseDefaulting(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), 1)
            .toFormatter();
    
    LocalDate weekStart = LocalDate.parse(calendarWeek, startOfWeekFormatter);
    LocalDate weekEnd = weekStart.plusWeeks(1);

    return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<LocalDate, LocalDate>(weekStart, weekEnd);
}
```

Printing the result in a `main` with your example `String` like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cw = "35/19";
    Map.Entry<LocalDate, LocalDate> calendarWeekStartAndEndDate
                                    = getStartAndEndOfCalendarWeek(cw);
    System.out.println(calendarWeekStartAndEndDate.getKey() 
            + " - " + calendarWeekStartAndEndDate.getValue());
}
```

would output

```
2019-08-26 - 2019-09-02
```

I know this adds a week to the result of using your `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the `String`, but I don't think involving two different parsers or parsing actions would cause any benefit over adding a week.

**If you want the starts of two consecutive calendar weeks, the make the addition add an additional day**, like this:

```
LocalDate weekEnd = weekStart.plusWeeks(1).plusDays(1);
```

and if you want a `LocalDateTime` (which is not quite clear to me if you really do), you could of course adjust the return type and use `.atStartOfDay()` when you parse the `weekStart`, the addition would stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd prefer an solution where I don't need to add the additional days
> to the result of the parsed string. Like a solution where the
> "plus(8)" is already included in the formatter.

That is not possible. You can’t parse `2020-08-30` into 2020-08-31 or 2020-09-30. Just as well you cannot parse `35/19` into a date in week 36 of 2019.

I’m all in favour of half-open intervals, so I do see that it would be practical in your situation. Sorry that it isn’t possible.

Link: [Half-Open Interval](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Half-OpenInterval.html) in WolframMathWorld.